talking animation with meta rig
I have 2 brief questions about this topic:

When I'm keyframing the character I've been selecting all of the controllers regardless if they are animating and keyframing them. Is this fine or do I need to only keyframe the controllers actually being moved?

While animating the meta rig to speak, something tells me there is an addon or something i could use to make it easier, or do I need to manually control every syllable?


I've had trouble finding answers to these questions online. Can anyone point me in the direction of some educational materials about this or clarify for me?
Thank you

1:
Keyframing everything is perfectly fine, the only downside is that the resulting animation datablock is heavier than what it could be, so if the animation has to be imported into a game engine, a final cleanup can be useful, deleting all keyframes that don't drive any motion, but generally speaking it'ok to have more keyframes than needed.
In the preferences window, Animation section, you can activate "Only insert available" (to automatically add keyframes only on bones that have been already manually keyframed) and "Only insert needed" (to add keyframes only where there is a value variation).
2:
Beside manual animation, where you generally prepare a pose library of all phonemes, then you manually recall every phoneme you need, many animators use some sort of facial motion capture, where an actor (or yourself) speaks out the dialogue and a camera is recording. Then some motion tracking is performed on the resulting video, and every moving point is associated with a face controller to rebuild the animation:
see this old but good YouTube tutorial for a homemade free solution to this problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNK8S19OSmA.
You can also use the graph editor menu Channel > Sound to samples to use the audio loudness to drive a bone, but results are generally quite approximated.
